# RODBC connectivity to Oracle without tnsnames.ora

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to Oracle from R using RODBC without using tnsnanes.ora.

I have tried following strings, but none of them are working.

```
> con.text <- paste0("Driver={OracleODBC-11g};Dbq=//oracle.server:1527/database.pdw.prod;Uid=user;Pwd=pswd;")

> con.text <- paste0("Driver={OracleODBC-11g}; ",
         "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.server)(PORT = 1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = database.pdw.prod))); uid=user;pwd=pswd;")

> con.text <- paste0("Driver=", "OracleODBC-11g"
                     , ";Server=", "oracle.server"
                     , ";Database=", "database.pdw.prod"
                     , ";Uid=", "user"
                     , ";Pwd=", "pwd", ";")

> con.text <- paste0("Driver=", "OracleODBC-11g"
                      , ";Server=", "oracle.server"
                      , ";CONNECTSTRING=" , "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.server)(PORT = 1527))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = database.pdw.prod)))" 
                      , ";Database=", "database.pdw.prod"
                      , ";Uid=", "user"
                      , ";Pwd=", "pswd", ";")
> con1 <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = con.text)
```

But for all these strings I am getting following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = con.text) :
 [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12162, message [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = con.text) : ODBC connection failed
```

OR

```
      1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = con.text) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Comment: Instead of `SERVICE_NAME`, try `SID`

Answer (score 5):

The correct sysntaxis you are looking for is

```
Conex     <- odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER=Oracle en OraClient11g_home2;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;DBQ=//HOSTNAME:PORT/ORACLE_SID;",
             believeNRows = FALSE)
```

Ex

```
Conex     <- odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER=Oracle en OraClient11g_home2;UID=John;PWD=Deere;DBQ=//fcoracleserver.youdomain:1521/TestEnvironment;",
             believeNRows = FALSE)
```

The hard part is to find the name of the Driver, as you can see mine is on spanish.

What I did is I create first a ODBC Conection using the C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe, there you can check the right name of your Oracle or SQL Server driver.

Once you create the conection, you can use
`odbcDataSources()` on R, to see that conection and to find out the driver. Thats really the hard part.

Hope it helps !