# Using the new odbc package with an IP address and no DSN with an Oracle server

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I can get the `odbc` package working in Windows so long as I add a DSN for my Oracle server, but I can't get it working at all otherwise. Namely, after adding a DSN entry named "DummyDB" which contains just an IP address and service ID (in addition to the driver, of course), this works:

```
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                  DSN = "DummyDB",
                  UID = credentials$login,
                  PWD = credentials$pw,
                  Port = 1521)
```

and yet this, with the exact same IP, driver, and service ID as in the DSN entry, does not (IP x'ed out for privacy):

```
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                  Driver = "Oracle in IC",
                  Host = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx",
                  SVC = "XE",
                  UID = credentials$login,
                  PWD = credentials$pw,
                  Port = 1521)
```

nor does this work:

```
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={Oracle in IC};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)));Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;")
```

And of course I've tried tweaking all of these every which way. No matter what, I get the always-mysterious:

`nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

Obligatory details:

- I am using my router software's VPN and port-forwarding, and those must be configured right enough for the DSN connection to succeed, pointing to the router's WAN IP.
- I've tried replacing my server's name with my router's IP (which my client system code is pointing to), and with my server's local IP, in both my tnsnames.ora and my listener.ora. I think I've tried every single combination there, stopping and starting the whole server each time, and waiting a minute after starting. With most of these combinations, actually, the DSN connection fails with `listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`. Meanwhile, the non-DNS connection fails with my good friend "protocol adapter error."
- I've tried using the server's local IP on my client, while my client is within the same LAN, and with that local IP in the .ora file(s). Same error. Simple IP pings work.

Perhaps a DSN added via the Data Source Administrator is a hard requirement here for some reason? At this point it'd be great to just have any example of someone successfully connecting to any (Oracle) server with this package but without using a client-side DSN entry.

Comment: *this does not work* is not helpful to us. Please edit your post with error messages as this indicates the issue.

Comment: I think you must define an alias for `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))` in your `tnsnames.ora` file. As far as I know you cannot use the full qualified name in ODBC.

Comment: You can set Data sources in ODBC Administrator also for current user which does not require any admin privileges. Anyway, if you provide the connect string as yo do, then it is not required.

Comment: @Parfait Edit made. Y'know I honestly forgot to mention the error because it's so friggin uninformative, at least to me after all these attempts.

Comment: @Wernfried-Domscheit I'm starting to wonder if I understood you right. What do you mean that you "cannot use the full qualified name in ODBC"? My `tnsnames.ora` edit just consisted of changing the `host` argument in the existing `XE = ` entry (and the `LISTENER = ` entry in `listener.ora`).

Comment: You can add ODBC data source also with a simple entry in Registry. Have a look at `HKCU\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources`, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI` At least the `HKCU` branch should be open even for non privileged users.

Comment: Please show content of your `tnsnames.ora` file, then it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having an identical problem and I tried all the same things. I finally resolved it by changing the `Host` argument to `DBQ` and adding the port and service name there:

```
vdw = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                     Driver= "My Oracle in Dir", # e.g. "Oracle in OraClient12Home1"
                     DBQ = "my-host-name.domain.org:1521/my-service-name",
                     Schema = "my_schema",
                     UID="my_userid",
                     PWD="my_password)
```

Hope that helps! This took me far too long to figure out... the answer was here: [RODBC connectivity to Oracle without tnsnames.ora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114170/rodbc-connectivity-to-oracle-without-tnsnames-ora)

Comment: Works perfectly for me! You're a lifesaver here. Thanks so much. PS: I didn't need to specify schema; not sure if that's just because I'm only aware of and using the default schema here,  but the argument is optional.